# How to get the list of class from the output of linq query

Tags: c#, linq

See following code:

```
public class Element
{
    public int num { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }

    public Element(int _num, string _name, int _age)
    {
        this.num = _num;
        this.name = _name;
        this.age = _age;
    }
}

List<Element> ItemCollection = new List<Element>();
ItemCollection.Add(new Element(1, "A", 25));
ItemCollection.Add(new Element(1, "B", 25));
ItemCollection.Add(new Element(1, "C", 25));
ItemCollection.Add(new Element(2, "B", 15));
ItemCollection.Add(new Element(3, "ada", 25));
ItemCollection.Add(new Element(3, "As", 25));
ItemCollection.Add(new Element(4, "as", 25));
ItemCollection.Add(new Element(5, "Asd", 25));
ItemCollection.Add(new Element(6, "Asd", 25));
ItemCollection.Add(new Element(6, "Asd", 23));

//Case of uniqueness
var UniqueNumberCollection = (from i in ItemCollection
                              where i.age > 20
                              group i by i.num into eCollection
                              where eCollection.Count() == 1                                          
                              select eCollection.Key).ToList();
```

Above code gives me the output as `4,5`

But I want the output as `4, "as", 25 and  5, "Asd", 25`

In other words i want entire element as output not the just the numbers

Comment: public class Element
    {
        public int num { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }

        public Element(int _num, string _name, int _age)
        {
            this.num = _num;
            this.name = _name;
            this.age = _age;
        }
    }

Comment: You've forgotten to add how you output your results. A guess says take the `.Key` part off your `select` so you get the `Element` grouped by its number.

Answer (score 1):

What the `GroupBy` does is it groups the elements into a collection by the `Key` (the only thing you're currently selecting).

When you say you want the entire element, you need to realize you either want `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` of that collection, or you're going to still be dealing with a list.

Given what you added to your question, this seems like something you'd want :

```
var UniqueNumberCollection = (from i in ItemCollection
                              where i.age > 20
                              group i by i.num into eCollection
                              where eCollection.Count() == 1                                          
                              select new { eCollection.Key, eCollection.FirstOrDefault().name, eCollection.FirstOrDefault().age }).ToList();
```

Comment: The key takeaway is that you understand how we got to the answer and that you understand what data types you are dealing with when you're dealing with things like an `IGrouping<T,T>`